Radius of convergence of Taylor series when a function has branch cuts
A function $f$ in the complex plane is holomorphic except for branch points and the branch cuts emanating from them. Suppose that all of the branch cuts point away from the origin; no branch cut approaches closer to the origin than any of its branch points. (See also a related question about when it is possible to do this.)
Suppose we know that the function $f$ is holomorphic at the origin.
Construct the Taylor expansion of $f$ about $z=0$.
Suppose the closest branch point of $f$ is a distance $R_b$ from the origin.
I think I know from Cauchy's theorem that the Taylor expansion about $z=0$ will converge, and will converge to $f$, for disks about the origin of radius $R < R_b$.
However, am I guaranteed that the Taylor expansion about $z=0$ will diverge (won't converge to anything, let alone converge to $f$) for $|z|=R > R_b$?

I am most interested in the case of "log-type" branch points and branch cuts; I have in mind $f$ being some appropriate branch of $\log(g)$ for a holomorphic $g$, like in my other related question.

Yes, this is guaranteed. If the Taylor series converged on a larger disk, then it would necessarily equal $f(z)$ on the larger disk by the uniqueness of analytic continuation, contradicting the fact that branch points are necessary (I'm assuming there's some nontriviality assumption on the branch points of $f(z)$).

+1 Thanks, I think analytic continuation was exactly what I was missing. Give me a day to make sure I understand the basics of analytic continuation, and then I'll accept. By nontriviality, are you imagining roughly like if the branch cut were put in by hand for no good reason? For example, (the following isn't a branch cut, but is it close in spirit to what you're thinking of ruling out?) if $f(z)=z$ everywhere but at $z=1$ it was set equal to $10$, the Taylor series $=z$ would converge everywhere despite there being funny behavior at $z=1$ in $f(z)$.

Yes—"branch point/branch cut" isn't super rigorously defined, and one could imagine some sort of "removable branch point"....
